# How to enable cubic lines in MPAndroidChart library?

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library for a project of mine to integrate charts in my app. I know how to use LineCharts but I couldn't figure out a way to use the Cubic Lines feature of the LineCharts. The image below shows the kind of graph i want, please let me know how to solve this issue.
[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try using something like this

```
lineDataSet.setDrawCubic(true);
```

It worked for me, here lineDataSet is your `LineDataSet` instance.

**Update** for v3.0.0 and onwards:

```
lineDataSet.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
```

Comment: does not work also for me, I'm using v3.1.0-alpha. I've also invalidated the chart after setting the `data` with the `dataSet` mode as `CUBIC_BEZIER`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add set mode of LineData set, enable draw filled and set the fill color

```
    lineDataSet.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER)
    lineDataSet.setDrawFilled(true)
    lineDataSet.setFillColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.green))
```