# Adding lineDataSet.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER) not working for Cubic Line Chart

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, mpandroidchart

I want to add Cubic Line Chart.I have reffered this ans:[How to enable cubic lines in MPAndroidChart library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892685/how-to-enable-cubic-lines-in-mpandroidchart-library)  but the solution is not working.Is there any solution?
I have **Mp Android Chart version-3.0.1**

Here is my code:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_graph_test, container, false);

    LineChart lineChart=view.findViewById(R.id.bar_Chart_test);

    List<Entry> entries=new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        entries.add(new Entry(i,i+3));
    }
    LineDataSet lineDataSet=new LineDataSet(entries,"My Line Chart");
    lineDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);


    LineData lineData=new LineData(lineDataSet);
    lineChart.setData(lineData);
    lineChart.invalidate();
    lineChart.animateXY(2000,2000);
    lineDataSet.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
    return view;
}
```

XML :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         tools:context="finlit.finlit.fragment.GraphTest">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"/>
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
    android:id="@+id/bar_Chart_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="478dp">
</com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the mode before you invalidate or animate the chart.
Because that actions will cause a redraw of your chart.

Comment: Working!!How can we set the color under the graph like green colored area under the graph in this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892685/how-to-enable-cubic-lines-in-mpandroidchart-library

Comment: in general you can find most informations in the wiki of this library https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki
for coloring the graph you can use `lineDataSet.setColor(color)` and `lineDataSet.setDrawFilled(true)`